# Making C++ Pi approximation running in Paralell on GPU Nvidia 970M CUDA's

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia, pi

I got this code from The Chudnovsky formula for Pi approximation and I want to do it faster and faster. But I have no experience or idea of how to deal with GPU's. How to make this code runs on GPU Nvidea 970M? It's on C++. There's some easy lib to make it? With my processor it's running about 3~4s...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

double fac(double num) {
    double result = 1.0;
    for (double i=2.0; i<num; i++)
       result *= i;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    double pi=0.0;
    for (double k = 0.0; k < 10.0; k++) {
        pi += (pow(-1.0,k) * fac(6.0 * k) * (13591409.0 + (545140134.0 * k)))
            / (fac(3.0 * k) * pow(fac(k), 3.0) * pow(640320.0, 3.0 * k + 3.0/2.0));
    }
    pi *= 12.0;
    cout << setprecision(100000000) << 1.0 / pi << endl;
system("Pause");    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: To take advantage of the multiple cores on a graphics card, you will need to split this into pieces that can be delegated to different cores; think of multi-threading.  For example you can divide the algorithm into two threads, one thread calculates the even values of `k`, the other thread calculates the odd values of `k`.  The `main` program can add these two together after the threads finish.

Comment: You can speed up your program by keeping 3 *running* factorial values.  Each factorial value will be multiplied by the next value of `k` (rather than restarting the factorial calculation from 1.0).

Comment: Another optimization is to calculate `fac(k)`, place into a temporary variable and multiply itself 3 times:  `double m = fac(k); double power3 = m * m * m;`.

Comment: according to my testing, all of the time in this code is spent in the `cout << setprecision(100000000)...` statement.  Replace that with a more reasonable `setprecision(40)` (although `double` is only going to give 10-15 digits of precision, at best) and the execution time drops to approximately 0 (~1 millisecond).  As a result of this, none of the proposed optimizations in the answer provided make any tangible difference.

Comment: for a bit of amusement, try running this code: `#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  double pi=1.0/3.0;
  cout << setprecision(100000000)  << pi << endl;
  return 0;}`  Take note of the output as well as the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Before delegating to a GPU with multiple cores, I suggest you optimize the algorithm with one core first.

### Running Factorial Values

Your factorial function is always starting at 2.0 for each value of k.  This has the following calculations:

```
+----+-------------------+  
| 1! | 1                 |   
+----+-------------------+  
| 2! | 1 * 2             |  
+----+-------------------+  
| 3! | 1 * 2 * 3         |  
+----+-------------------+  
| 5! | 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 |   
+----+-------------------+
```

These time of these iterations will add up as the values of `k` get larger.

The factorial can be expressed iteratively as:

```
+----+--------+   
| 1! | 1      |   
+----+--------+  
| 2! | 1! * 2 |  
+----+--------+  
| 3! | 2! * 3 |  
+----+--------+  
| 5! | 4! * 5 |   
+----+--------+
```

In other words, the next factorial uses the previous *factorial value* and multiplies by the value of `k`.

Your `main` could look like:

```
    int main()
    {
      double k_factorial = 1.0;
      //...
      for (/* ... */)
      {
        if (k > 1.0) k_factorial *= k;
        //...
                / (fac(3.0 * k) * pow(k_factorial, 3.0) * pow(640320.0, 3.0 * k + 3.0/2.0));
    //...
  }
```

Since you have 3 different factorials:  `fac(3.0 * k), fac(k),` and `fac(6.0 * k)`, you could use 3 different factorial variables and update their values inside the `for` loop.

### Running `pow` variables

Similar to the factorial variables, you can have running values for the `pow` functions.
The `pow(-1.0, k)` can be replaced by:

```
double pow_sign = 1.0; // pow(-1.0, 0)
//...
for (//...
{
  pow_sign *= -1.0;
  pi += (pow_sign * //...
```

Also, we know that `pow(x, 3)` is the same as `x * x * x`.  Making the substitution:
`pow(fac(k), 3.0)` --> `factorial_k * factorial_k * factorial_k`

### Algebraic Simplification

You can also simplify your assignment statement algebraically.
For example, make a table consisting of the following columns:

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+  
|  k  | fac(6.0 * k) | fac(3.0 * k) |  
+-----+--------------+--------------+  
|  0  |              |              |  
+-----+--------------+--------------+  
|  1  |              |              |  
+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

See if you notice any patterns.
Also rewrite the assignment vertically to see if you can simplify by factoring.

### Exploiting GPU cores

Once you have optimized the calculation to a running or iterative approach, you can delegate to multiple cores.

The first step is to figure out how you can divide the work into pieces that can be run in parallel.

Split your calculations into three pieces and run (on one core).  Verify correctness.

Next step is to either research "c++ parallel programming" for instructions on how to run the program using parallel processing on your platform, or search the internet on "c++ use gpu multiple cores".

You want the amount of work that each core receives to consume more time that the overhead of setting up the cores.